# Core Data: Emitting KVO notifications for transient, derived properties

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, key-value-observing

I have `Parent` entity with a custom class that has a transient and derived (read only) property called `DerivedProperty`.

The value of `DerivedProperty` is dependent on the value of `Parent.IndependentProperty1` and so whenever `IndependentProperty1` changes, the value of `DerivedProperty` will change. However, `Parent` has a to-many relationship to `Child` (called `children`) and `DerivedProperty` is also dependent on the value of `IndependentProperty2` in all of `Parent`'s `Child` objects.

So whenever `IndependentProperty1` of `Parent` or `IndependentProperty2` of any of the `Child` objects changes, I would like to notify any observers that `DerivedProperty` has also changed.

I've arrived at the following code so far. The only problem is that no KVO notifications are emitted for `DerivedProperty` since if I try to do this in `objectContextDidChange:` then the code will end up in a loop.

```
- (void) awakeFromInsert
{
    [super awakeFromInsert];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(objectContextDidChange:) name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification object:self.managedObjectContext];
}


- (void) awakeFromFetch
{
    [super awakeFromFetch];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(objectContextDidChange:) name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification object:self.managedObjectContext];
}

- (void) objectContextDidChange: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSSet *updatedObjects = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey];

    if ([updatedObjects containsObject:self] || [updatedObjects intersectsSet:self.children])
    {
        //clear caches
        _derivedProperty  = nil;
    }
}

- (void) didTurnIntoFault
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (NSString *) DerivedProperty
{
    if (_derivedProperty == nil)
    {
        _derivedProperty  = [self someExpensiveCalculation];
    }
    return _derivedProperty  ;
}
```

I'm sure I need a total rethink on my approach here. I've tried using KVO to observe `IndependentProperty1` and `IndependentProperty2` of the to-many relation but I just can't seem to get it working right. If the derived property wasn't dependent on a to-many relationship then I'm sure I could just use `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:` but of course that won't work across a to-many relationship.

How to I get KVO notifications working with a Core Data transient, derived property that is dependent on a to-many relationship?

Comment: I cannot test this at the moment, but what about working the other way around: The setter function for `IndependentProperty2` of the Children entity calls a method on its parent that computes and sets the `DerivedProperty` ?

Comment: That would work but it doesn't play nice with my domain model. The `Child` objects shouldn't know anything about their `Parent` nevermind be responsible for updating it. I might end up having to go down this route though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are accessing the ivar for `DerivedProperty` in your `-objectContextDidChange:` method and that short circuits KVO notifications.  You should really re-implement the property internally as read/write and use the generator accessor.

Second, subclasses of `NSManagedObject` have automatic KVO turned off by default.  This is part of the architecture of Core Data.  Therefore you would want to fire the notifications yourself if you are not going to use an accessor:

```
- (void) objectContextDidChange: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSSet *updatedObjects = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey];

    if ([updatedObjects containsObject:self] || [updatedObjects intersectsSet:self.children]) {
        //clear caches
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"derivedProperty"];
        _derivedProperty  = nil;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"derivedProperty"];
    }
}
```

### Note

In this case the OP was using a transient property **AND** accessing an iVar for the property directly. This effectively created two iVars, one maintained by Core Data and another maintained by the OP's code.  This was causing a collision.

If you are using a transient property it is recommended that you move calculations to another method as suggested and leave the accessors to Core Data.

Comment: On your first point, I was doing this. The external interface exposes a `readonly` whilst the internal interface redefines it as `readwrite`. I probably scrapped it because as you say automatic KVO is disabled for `NSManagedObject`. I'm not able to test your suggestion right now but I'm sure that when I tried firing the notifications like this I just ended up in a loop - `derivedProperty` is changed so `objectContextDidChange:` gets called again, and so on.

Comment: If you are getting a loop then you are doing -willChange in both places which you don't want to do.  Ideally you should have a `-recalculate` method that changes the value so that you can call `-recalculate` from `-objectContextDidChange:` and from `-derivedProperty` as needed. Then `-recalculate` would be the only place that changes the value and calls `-willChangeValueForKey:` and `-didChangeValueForKey:`.

Comment: I've tried as you suggested by putting `willChange...` and `didChange...` inside `objectContextDidChange.` When I attempt to call save on the MOC it never returns and appears to be in an infinite notification loop. There is no other part of the class making these `willChange...` and `didChange...` calls. Any ideas?

Comment: Deleting `derivedProperty` from the MOM seems to have stopped the looping. Previously it was defined as a transient property in the model.

Comment: That would make sense. If you have a transient in the model then the ivar you were manipulating directly was not the same (or should not be the same) as the one Core Data is expecting you to manipulate. Another reason to use the accessors ONLY and to move calculations to another method.

Comment: Thanks for your help Marcus, it all seems to be working very well now. Might be worth mentioning transient properties in your answer since my question states I was using them (for no practical purpose apparently).

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra I know this question is old, but I have been looking diligently for an example of exactly what you are saying to do for this question (-recalculate method that can be called from -objectContextDidChange: and from -derivedProperty as needed). I am having trouble figuring out how to call -recalculate from these methods - do you happen to have an example of where this is done?

Comment: What I am asking is, based on Marcus' first comment above, if `-willChangeValueForKey:` and `-didChangeValueForKey:` are used in `-recalculate`, how is the value actually set? It is a derived property (no longer transient, and not persisted, right ? I could be wrong..) so I believe we cannot use `setPrimitiveValue:forKey:`; am I correct when I summarize what Marcus is saying as: the options are 1) use `-willChangeValueForKey:`, `-didChangeValueForKey:`, and the set the value via the ivar or 2) use the generated accessor (`setValue:forKey`) in  `-recalculate`?

Comment: If my above summarization is correct, the only reason I can think that the first option (ivar) should be used is to make sure that the value isn't set if it is the same as the current value. This might be worthwhile, although I believe it would necessitate the use of `@synthesize`, which I thought was discouraged at this point.