# NSManagedObjectContext does not notify observer of changes for transients

Tags: ios, core-data, formatting, nsnotificationcenter, key-value-observing

I am trying to clean up some transient property recalculation events. In development I have just used a very broad stroke of updating on almost all changes. Now I am trying to determine the best practice, checking for relevant keys and updating as little as needed. My application objects are loaded with dozens of calculations using child and parent attributes where a single change can result in many cascading recalculations.

I thought I understood fairly well, referring to Apple Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002179-BAJEAIEE) and I have experimented with patterns seen on some other StackOverflow posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738126/core-data-emitting-kvo-notifications-for-transient-derived-properties) one by @Marcus S. Zarra. I see Marcus also posted an article on the subject [here](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/10/14/parent-watching-its-child/).

What I have currently is this:

```
#pragma mark _ worksheetTotal (transient)

+(NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingWorksheetTotal
{
    // local, non-transient, dependent keys here
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"dailySustenance", nil];
}

-(void)updateWorksheetTotal
{
    NSDecimalNumber *lineItemTotal = [self.items valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.lineHoursCost"];
    NSDecimalNumber *total = [lineItemTotal decimalNumberByAdding:self.dailySustenance];

    [self setWorksheetTotal:total];
}

-(void)setWorksheetTotal:(NSDecimalNumber *)newWorksheetTotal
{
    if ([self worksheetTotal] != newWorksheetTotal) {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"worksheetTotal"];
        [self setPrimitiveWorksheetTotal:newWorksheetTotal];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"worksheetTotal"];
    }
}

-(NSDecimalNumber *)worksheetTotal
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"worksheetTotal"];
    NSDecimalNumber *result = [self primitiveWorksheetTotal];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"worksheetTotal"];

    return result;
}
```

I am thinking this is straight out of the documentation use case but my observers are not getting notified of the the changes to worksheetTotal.

When a change is made to a lineItem, that notification is received and responds `updateWorksheetTotal` is called here. I expect this would trigger another notification by the context that worksheetTotal has now changed, but it does not. I have tried numerous variations and combinations of code I have seen but nothing I do seems to make the `NSManagedObjectContext` consider my update to `worksheetTotal` to be a change worth reporting to observers.

What am I missing here?

Here is the relevant code for listening for the change in Parent object.

```
- (void) objectContextDidChange: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSSet *updatedObjects = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey];
    // Next look for changes to worksheet that may affect our calculated fields
    NSPredicate *worksheetPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entity.name == %@ && estimate == %@", @"LaborWorksheet", self];
    NSPredicate *materialsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entity.name == %@ && estimate == %@", @"MaterialLineItems", self];
    NSPredicate *combinedPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:worksheetPredicate, materialsPredicate, nil]];
    NSSet *myWorksheets = [updatedObjects filteredSetUsingPredicate:combinedPredicate];
    // These are the relevant keys in this estimates labor and materials worksheet
    NSSet *relevantKeys = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"worksheetTotal", @"totalEquipmentcost", nil];
    BOOL clearCache = NO;
    if (myWorksheets.count != 0) {
        for (NSManagedObject *worksheet in myWorksheets) {
            NSLog(@"got some");
            // Here is where it fails, worksheetTotal is not in changedValues.allKeys. It is an empty set.
            // Not sure how that could be when I got it from updatedObjects set of userInfo. How could it have no changed values?
            NSSet *changedKeys = [NSSet setWithArray:worksheet.changedValues.allKeys];
            if ([changedKeys intersectsSet:relevantKeys]) {
                clearCache = YES;
                NSLog(@"found some, set to clear cache");
                // no need to continue checking
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (clearCache) {
      // I would update dependent keys here but it is never reached

    }
 }
```

Comment: How are your observers listening for this change?

Comment: @JesseRusak I added an example to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the `changedValues` method says:

> This method only reports changes to properties that are defined as
>   persistent properties of the receiver, not changes to transient
>   properties or custom instance variables. This method does not
>   unnecessarily fire relationship faults.

Since your property is transient, it will not appear there. I would suggest using [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) to monitor the changes in these properties.

Comment: Doh! I should have looked at that documentation of changedValues. That never occurred to me. I do believe it though. I have tried innumerous configurations to force that sucker in there. Did learn a  lot. I don't want to give up on using observation of the context rather than individual KVO. There are too many of these to keep after. I am going to try adding a flag that does report and set that when recalculation is needed. Thanks Jesse.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning before didAccessValueForKey. Store to a variable and return it after didAccessValueForKey like

```
-(NSDecimalNumber *)worksheetTotal
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"worksheetTotal"];
    NSDecimalNumber *yourVariable = [self primitiveWorksheetTotal];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"worksheetTotal"];
    return yourVariable;
}
```

I hope it works.

**Edit:**

In

```
-(void)setWorksheetTotal:(NSDecimalNumber *)newWorksheetTotal
```

consider changing

```
if ([self worksheetTotal] != newWorksheetTotal) {
```

to

```
if (worksheetTotal != newWorksheetTotal) {
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified and it seemed to make no difference.